# SELECT count() with full-text query

Tags: sql, mysql

What is the proper syntax for counting the results from the following query?

```
SELECT title,keyword, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM video 
WHERE MATCH (keyword) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND active = "1" 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...`

Comment: Why do you think `SELECT COUNT(*)` works differenly when you use full-text matching?

Comment: If you try what you're saying it produces a syntax error which is why this post was created....

Comment: This is a complex query that requires special syntax to use COUNT() and everything I've tried fails. Just seeking some assistance of the proper syntax to count the results of the provided query. Your response completely disregards the provided input.

Comment: Do you want a total count, or a count per title and keyword? Please show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: It's confusing the way you have both `keyword` as a column name and you're also matching against the literal string `keyword`.

Comment: To clarify, "keyword" refers to any user input and it matches against a list of keywords stored in the database. I just need to count the number of results that the query produces.

Comment: You say it's complex, but it sounds simple to me, so obviously there's something I'm not understanding from your description. Please show sample data and expected result.

Comment: Why do you match the title in the `SELECT` list, but `keyword` in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: It takes the user input and matches it against the title and a list of keywords and it generates a list ordered by relevance in which the user input matches both columns. Do you see a more logical way of doing this?

Comment: The query itself works fine so I don't really want to distract from that too much on this question as I really just need to count the output of the query.

Comment: Why doesn't it work if just change the select list to `SELECT COUNT(*)`? That counts the number of rows in the output of the query.

Comment: Because it produces a syntax error as this query requires a lot of special syntax such as the comma after the second select option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the select list with `COUNT(*)` to get the count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM video 
WHERE MATCH (keyword) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND active = "1"
```

Comment: Thanks. That appears to do the trick. D you see a more logical way to write that query? The goal is to take the user input and find the best match between both the title and keyword columns which is seems to do well but I'm curious if there is a better way as you seemed to be confused by it.

Comment: I think your query already finds the best match. Getting the count of all matches is completely separate. Are you asking how to combine them into one query?

Comment: Most SQL APIs have a function to return the number of rows in the result set. So if you perform a query that gets all the matches, just ask it for the row count to get this information, you don't need a separate query.

Comment: I guess it's not necessary to combine them as going off the where clause yields the correct total. Ya, that's an interesting point which I didn't think of.

Comment: I'm curious how this is different from what you tried that had a syntax error.

Comment: I was trying to incorporate count() with the match() against the title column.